# I cannot detect my wireless headphone in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, headset

My headphone model is QCY-QY7, use bluetooth to connect with my laptop
When i use win10, i use it normally
but when i change to ubuntu 18.04 lts, my laptop cannot detect my headphone
anymore.
What i should do?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please add more details about your computer? As much as you know about the configuration, especially Bluetooth module.

Comment: Try installing blueman and connecting the headset

Comment: Have you paired the headphones again in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by clicking on the menu settings at the right corner where battery icon is, then clicking on bluetooth -> settings and from there turn the bluetooth off and on and wait til u see ur headset on the list.